# How to recover a GB2312 encoded file which is load and saved in UTF8?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a file which is GB2312 encoded, but load and saved in UTF8 by mistake. And it looks like the following:

```
���ͣ�
```

However the correct word should be

```
微信
```

I am wondering if there is some way I can recover this file? I have tried the following python code, which in my thought is a reversed procedure, however it does not work.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("new.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
text = text.decode()
print text
text = text.encode('gb2312')
with codecs.open("trans_new", 'w', encoding='gb2312') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

So I begin to think if there are some infomation loss that make it impossible to recover this file?

EDIT

I am using python 2.

The actual bytes by `repr(f.read())` are

```
'\xce\xa2\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

Comment: Can you share the actual bytes (`open('new.txt', 'rb').read()`)?  Also, are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @snakecharmerb see my update

Comment: `\xef\xbf\xbd` *is* the � character. There's nothing to recover from that.

Comment: `b'\xce\xa2\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd'.decode('gb2312')` gives `'微锟斤拷'`…

Comment: @JosefZ 锟斤拷  is the equivalent of Mojibake in Chinese. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7#:~:text=%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7%EF%BC%8C%E6%98%AF%E4%B8%80,%E4%B9%8B%E9%97%B4%E7%9A%84%E8%BD%AC%E6%8D%A2%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E3%80%82

Comment: @Josef Translation: Kunjinkao(锟斤拷) is a string of garbled characters often seen on search engine pages and other websites. The garbled code stems from the conversion problem between the GBK character set and the Unicode character set.